# Split string into groups of five

Tags: php, string

I have this string:

```
string='101,102,103,105,201,250,2564,245564,212,2415,2102,5645,656';
```

I want to split it into groups of 5.

Output should be:

```
array
{
    [0]=101,102,103,105,201
    [1]=250,2564,245564,212,2415
    [2]=2102,5645,656
}
```

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: What's the problem you're having? What have you tried so far? Please post the code which you're currently using.

Comment: Is this string length is fix?
And do you always want first five elements at 0 key in array
next 5 in  1 key in array and 
rest in 2 key?
Is this string is fix of varies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$str = "101,102,103,105,201,250,2564,245564,212,2415,2102,5645,656";

$arr = explode(",", $str);
$arr_chunk = array_chunk($arr, 5);

$arr_output = array();
foreach($arr_chunk as $arr_val)
{
  $arr_output[] = implode(",", $arr_val);
}

print_r($arr_output);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 101,102,103,105,201
    [1] => 250,2564,245564,212,2415
    [2] => 2102,5645,656
)
```

SEE **[FIDDLE DEMO](http://codepad.org/A9tJCLBi)**

Answer (score 0):

Another method

```
<?php
$string = '101,102,103,105,201,250,2564,245564,212,2415,2102,5645,656';
$parts  = explode(",", $string);   
$cnt    = count($parts)/5;
for($i=0; $i<ceil($cnt); $i++) { 
   $arr[$i] = implode(",", array_slice($parts, $i*5, 5));
}
print_r($arr);
?>
```